# Electromagnetic pendulum (pulse movement)

Tags: electromagnetic

I would like to make a cost effective (without using large circuit and micro controller and all) **electromagnetic pendulum** for my **wooden clock** (so the second wheel will move according to pendulum swings). So i found  a simple tutorial from this link (http://www.trainelectronics.com/Pendulum/article.htm). But unfortunately it's not swinging properly pulse wise. Can anyone figure out my problem like am I missing any components or need to increese battery power or coil turn something like that? Working solutions will get appreciated.

Note: I'm a beginner to electronics.
Here is my circuit details.

- Battery - Duracell-2 (1.5 V)
- Components used - As said in tutorial (You can see the circuit from tutorial link)
- Coil - 500 turn (28 gauge)
- Input voltage - 3V output voltage- 0.8 V (observed in multimeter)
- Round neodymium magnet

### Observed

The LED glows only when coil not connected to the circuit.

### Expected Output

```
1. Swinging pendulum pulsewise
2. Blinking LED when magnet cross coil
```

[image]

Comment: You need to include the schematic.  Make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: Do you have your batteries in parallel? That will only give 1.5 volts. You need them in series (3V).

Comment: @JRE circuit provided in the link

Comment: @WhayRoughBeast , excuse me the battery in parallel connection (in a battery holder) and it gives 3V correctly

Comment: Yeah, and lots of folks who could help won't bother if they have to follow a link then scroll through a long page to find the diagram.

Comment: The disc magnet polarity may be wrong. If so, try flipping your coil over and see if that corrects the problem.

Comment: @JRE,Ok i have uppdated my question with circuit.Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Optionparty,yes i have tried by flipping,actually the coil have a magnetic field around it so that the magnet get repelled when flip over the coil. But the problem is it's not coming back properly and no uniform motion(not swinging properly).Can you please tell me what will be the reason the LED is not blinking when i flip over the coil??

Comment: This possible duplicate should help - fiund with a search : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/145612/152903